# VBA for Excel: How to easily reference to index of the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to reference to the row and column indices of the currently active cell. I tried something like

```
Cells(ActiveCell.RowIndex, 5).Value = "something"
```

But that gave me run time error 438.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use:

`ActiveCell.Row` and `ActiveCell.Column`

I would use it like:

`Range(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = "something"`

Comment: thank you so much! Where can I find a simple VBA documentation?